# Seeking explanation for: $ I-\frac{d^{2}I}{db^{2}}=0\:\: \Rightarrow I=A e^{ab}+Be^{-ab}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I found a beautiful proof for  $I=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\cos{bx}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}\: dx={\frac{\pi}{ae^{ab}}}$

However in the proof there is certain spot the following implication is made:

$ I-\frac{d^{2}I}{db^{2}}=0\:\: \Rightarrow I=A e^{ab}+Be^{-ab} \qquad  (*) $

It's easy to see that the differential equation $ y(t) = y''(t)$ has the general solution: $y(t) = Ae^t + Be^{-t} $

However looking at $(*)$ how does the $a$ get into the exponent?

Since it's in the exponent, I would expect the characteristic equation of $(*)$ to be $r^2 - a^2 = (r-a)(r+a) $ giving the desired the solutions $-a,a$.

Is this correct? What am I missing? I am thankful for any constructive comment or answer.

$$$$$$$$

Additional Note:

One can also easily verify that $A = 0$ and $B = \frac{\pi}{a}$ looking at the beginning equation.

According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+-inf+to+inf+of+(cos(x))%2F(a%5E2+%2Bx%5E2))
, the $a$ in the exponent seems indeed to be mandatory:
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\cos{x}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}\: dx={\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-a}$

I would really appreciate, if someone would point out

Comment: How do you get $I-\frac {d^2I}{db^2}=0$?

Comment: Is knowing that neccessary? Well it's basically the whole point of the proof, how and why it is so beautiful, (it also not very short or straightforward). 
If you have access to brilliant.org, the whole proof can be viewed in the solutions here:
https://brilliant.org/problems/do-you-really-need-contour-here2/?ref_id=1348781

Comment: 1) If $I$ is a linear combination of $e^{\pm ab}$, then it satisfies $a^2I-\frac{d^2I}{db^2}=0$ not the stated ODE. One could presumably start from the $a=1$ case and generalize from there, but as written the implication isn't sound. 2) The solution you link to is behind a registration screen.

Comment: @Semiclassical  you are awesome! Mathematicians in general are! Indeed the mistake was that the $a^2$ in the whole (!) solution went missing. It took me actually a while to understand the whole proof, but eventually I found it. Then of course it would also not appear in the ODE! Nonetheless her final result is correct.

Comment: Regarding point 2): That's unfortunate. Personally I don't want to simply copy someones solutions out from another source.. somehow I find this morally wrong.